# How does list comprehension rewrite a new list "behind scenes"?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So, in this example I understand how does it work:

```
# Create a list of numbers
user_entries = ["10", "19.1", "20"]

# Create an empty list to store the float numbers
float_numbers = []

# Iterate over the elements in the list
for number in user_entries:
  # Convert the element to float type and append it to the float_numbers list
  float_numbers.append(float(number))

# Calculate the sum of the numbers in the float_numbers list
print(sum(float_numbers))
```

But next code works same way, but I don't really understand how does it rewrite "behind scenes". In debugging I cannot see the movement of the second code.

```
user_entries = ['10', '19.1', '20']
user_entries = [float(item) for item in user_entries]
print(sum(user_entries))
```

Comment: But your second code is different to your first: The first creates `float_numbers` which you print (the sum of). The second overwrites `user_entries`.

Comment: `[ACTION for ITEM in CONTAINER]` same as `for ITEM in CONTAINER: LIST.add(ACTION)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: you assign a list of values to a variable (whether it already has assigned value doesn't matter). Are you unsure about how list comprehension works, assigning values to variables?

Comment: Your list comprehension is essentially a generator which is invoked until exhausted, with each result value being appended to the list that is being created (*not* rewritten, since it is being created from scratch).  But in your example, creating an actual list is pointless and memory-inefficient.  Instead, just do `sum(float(item) for item in user_entries)`, or `sum(map(float, user_entries))`.  This avoids the creation of a temporary list.

Comment: `import dis` and try `dis.dis("[float(item) for item in user_entries]")`